# Compile multiple stylesheets with Compass, different output style and ".min" file name

Tags: compilation, config, compass-sass, minify

Summary: Using Compass, need to compile SASS stylesheets twice with different output styles and file names.

I have this as my config.rb:

```
http_path           = "/"
css_dir             = "assets/css"
sass_dir            = "assets/sass"
# …more stuff… #
output_style        = :expanded
```

which perfectly compiles

```
assets 
┗ sass
   ┣ style1.scss
   ┗ style2.scss
```

to

```
assets 
┗ css
   ┣ style1.css
   ┗ style2.css
```

What I need to accomplish is an output like this:

```
assets 
┗ css
   ┣ style1.css
   ┣ style1.min.css
   ┣ style2.css
   ┗ style2.min.css
```

where ".min.css" files contain minified CSS, obviously.

So I figured I need to come up with something like:

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
    # switch output_style to :compressed
    # compile again and include ".min" into file name
end
```

Can any one provide me with a basic sample on how to accomplish that? 
Have not messed with ruby so far, but am coming to a basic understanding through all the reading I've been doing on this topic. ;) 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest [Yeoman](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/yeoman-build), or a custom [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) script. You could also use [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) if you're more Ruby-oriented.

Answer (score 2):

(Can't comment because of rep)

To answer Kevin Suttle, gulp could also do this job. It's kind of like grunt, but in gulp you get a code over configuration while grunt is mainly configuration and no (or almost no) code.

Many articles says that people learned grunt in over a day, while they spent only an hour learning about gulp.

It's up to you.

PS : Yeah, that post is from 2013 but answering it may help people having the same or a similar issue.